# Why the same css animation sometimes works incorrect?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I use CSS to animate the size of the div. I need the div to grow in size from its center.

But for some reason at some places on the page, it works fine, and in other places, it doesn't work, and the div is growing from its upper left corner.

[image]

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you animating the size change? Please add enough code to reproduce here.

Comment: Please post a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

Documentation of FlexBox: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 2s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.circle.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle.out {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.circle.in {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

.circle.animate {
  animation-name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bigger {
  from {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  to {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle out red">
  <div class="circle in blue animate"></div>
</div>
```